# Ajax alert message persists after clicking okay button

Tags: javascript, laravel

my code works alright but the alert message in the browser doesn't go away after I click the okay button inside the alert success prompt. I've tried all I can but still persists. Please help.

**HTML**

```
<button  id="flag-post" data-post-id="{{ $counter->id }}">Report this</button>
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('/flag', [App\Http\Controllers\ApplicationsController::class, 'flagPost'])->name('flag.post');
```

**Controller**

```
 public function flagPost(Request $request)
{
   
    $postId = $request->input('post_id');
    
    $post = Job::findOrFail($postId);
    
    $post->increment('flags');
    
    return response()->json(['success' => true]);
}
```

**Javascript**

```
<script>
    $(function() {
    $('#flag-post').click(function() {
    // Retrieve the post ID from the button's data attribute
    var postId = $(this).data('post-id');
    
    // Send an AJAX request to the flag post route
    $.ajax({
        url: "{{ route('flag.post') }}",
        type: "GET",
        data: {
            post_id: postId,
            _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}"
        },
        success: function(response) {
            // Alert the user that the post has been flagged
            alert("Thank you for flagging this post!");
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            // Alert the user that there was an error
            alert("Error: " + error);
        }
    });
});
});

    </script>
```

Comment: The only reason I can think about is that might your success callback is being called many times and there could be a resultant stack of alerts one behind another. Instead of an alert can you try the console to check how many times your success callback is triggering?

Answer (score -1):

try this way:

```js
function flagPost() {
  $(document).on('click', '#flag-post', function() {
    // Retrieve the post ID from the button's data attribute
    let postId = $(this).data('post-id');
    $.get('{{route("flag.post")}}', {
      post_id: postId,
      _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}"
    }).done(function (resp){
      alert("Thank you for flagging this post!");
    }).fail(function () {
      alert("Error");
    });
  });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  flagPost();
});
```

However i advise you to use `post` with method `put`

Comment: Your code just adds more complexity to the OP's code but doesn't do anything different than OP's

Comment: @AnujShrestha, what do you think is the problem?

Comment: @Philly did you do a console check as mentioned in the comment? Also, it is a browser alert so it should have closed by default. It is outside of users/developers control.